# How to format a string so that it prints 4 digits and 2 decimals

Tags: java, string, decimal, string-formatting

I am trying to print out a double that is always 4 digits as well as has 2 decimal places.

For example, If the number was `105.456789`
my `String.Format` would print out 0105.45
I understand that `%.2f` allows for the two decimal place problem.
I also understand that `%04d` allows for the 4 digit problem
However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to combine the two.

I have tried doing a double `String.format` 
I have tried doing one `String.format` and using both `%04d` and `%.2f`

```
System.out.println(String.format("Gross Pay:     $%.2f %04d", 105.456789));
```

I expect the output to be 0105.45 but I can't even get it to compile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things: first of all, your code **does** compile. But it immediately fails at runtime:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%04d'

Because: you are using **two** patterns in your format spec, but provide only one value.

Yes, `%.2f %04d` that are **two** specs, not one.

( Please let that sink in: there is a distinct difference between compile time errors and runtime exceptions. And it is important to understand that difference. )

Back to the "real" problem. Instead of using two patterns for one value, you have to thus use *one* spec, like:

```
System.out.println(String.format("Gross Pay:     $%07.2f", 105.456789));
```

> Gross Pay:     $0105.46

The "trick": that number *in front* of the "dot" needs to account for the **overall** desired length. Overall, you want: 4 digits+dot+2 digits, resulting in 7 chars. And 0 to fill upfront.

Thus your spec needs to start with "07".

Comment: Also, it is worth noting that %.2f also performs round-off, in case if the number exceeds 2 decimal places. And, $%07.2f also makes sure if the number is more than 5 characters in length, it does not truncate the non-decimal part. So, Need not always be resulting in 7 chars, Just in case!

Answer (score 0):

**This will give you exactly what you want:**

```
double num = 105.456789;
System.out.println(String.format("Gross Pay:     $%04.0f", num) +
        "." + String.valueOf(num).split("\\.")[1].substring(0,2));
```

**Output:**

```
Gross Pay:     $0105.45
```

**Explanation:**
As far as I know you can't take the 2 digits after the point with `String.format` without rounding (please correct me if I'm wrong), so I suggest using the [`split`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java) method. If you want you can cram this all into one statement like I did but it isn't very pretty so its up to you.